# dots and lines rebus

Tags: cipher, rebus

Find a sentence from this Rebus.

> **Eight dots five dots nine dots seven lines**

I am sure puzzle masters here can solve this rebus

Comment: Neat but... this isn't really a [tag:rebus]? [tag:cipher] seems right though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sentence is:

> **She is his mom.**

How can it be found?

> Dots and lines (or dashes) suggest Morse code. We are looking for words made up of all dots or all dashes. The letters we can use are:
>
> ```
>             · E                - T
>            ·· I               -- M
>           ··· S              --- O
>          ···· H
> ```
>
> Trying out some combinations yields the sentence above.